# Meteor's ServiceConfiguration broken after Meteor Reset

Tags: meteor

This error occurred after I run `meteor reset` on my project

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
at onLoginWithGoogle (Heading.js:23)
at Button._this.handleClick (modules.js?hash=aa2df6fbe7f4a6a52d262a213d0cfff2a56dcdc2:10098)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (modules.js?hash=aa2df6fbe7f4a6a52d262a213d0cfff2a56dcdc2:32249)
...
```

This is the file that is calling the ServiceConfiguration:

*Heading.js*

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import ServiceConfiguration from 'meteor/service-configuration'
...

function Heading(props){
    const context = useContext(Context);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const onLoginWithGoogle = () => {
        const {scope} = ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'google'}); //this is where it failed

        Meteor.loginWithGoogle(
          {requestPermissions: scope, requestOfflineToken: true },
          error => {
            if (error) {
              if (error.errorType === 'Accounts.LoginCancelledError') return;
              alert('Login error', error);
            } else {
              //
            }
          }
        );
    };
}
//export
```

The serviceconfiguration is stored on `server` folder under `service-configuration.js` file:

```
import { ServiceConfiguration } from 'meteor/service-configuration';

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
  { service: 'google' },
  {
    $set: {
      clientId: 'XXX',
      loginStyle: 'popup',
      secret: 'XXXX'
    }
  }
);
```

I can't get my head around this error. It was working before I run `meteor reset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Answering this to help others who might have bumped into this issue too, in the future.

Since I did `meteor reset`, the project is reset to `0`. So I need to re-insert the service configuration details into the mongo collection `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration`... I think I've accidentally deleted the upsert command on my `server/main.js` file somehow. So after I did the `meteor reset`, the serviceconfiguration is empty, and there's no code in the `Meteor.startup()` that replenish the details needed.

Here's the code that should stay in the `server/main.js`:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
      service: "google"
    });
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.upsert(
    { service: 'google' },
    {
      $set: {
        clientId: 'XXX', // change this to your actual clientId
        loginStyle: 'popup',
        secret: 'XXX' //change this to your actual secret
      }
    }
  );

});
```

In case if you're wondering how to the the `clientId` and `secret`, head to Google APIs Console [here](https://console.developers.google.com/), create a new project, and configure the Credentials, and OAuth consent screen accordingly.